# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Economics's [first moderator election](https://economics.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: 1muflon1]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5795186513805312/0).

Comment: Congrats @1muflon1! Glad to have you on the team!

Comment: Congratulations muflon and welcome to the team :)

Comment: thanks guys ^^ I am looking forward helping you  with moderation :)

Comment: Congrats! Well deserved.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations! I believe that you will be a good mod.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do my best :)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk thanks :)

Comment: Congrats @1muflon1!

Comment: @emeryville thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Some good numbers related to the interest/participation by users in the election:

In a recent moderator election in the statistics community Cross Validated, there were 705 ballots cast. In the last 4 months, posts (questions and answers) in CV hovered around 1,050 per week.

In our site, there were 121 ballots cast. Posts in the last three months were around 120 per week.